# what causes Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: capybara, minitest

• Rails 6

• Minitest with Capybara

In this spec I'm debugging, I am seeing my specs pass if I run each one *individually* (using `:` and the line number of the spec)

However, if I run them all, I consistently get this result:

```
Error:
Capybara::Portal::Desktop::SomeTest#test_submit_form_request:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When it runs, it appears to open Chrome momentarily before closing it.